# How does fast food restaurants make grilled chicken

Tags: chicken, grilling

In most of the fast food restaurants which do grilled chicken, when they get an order, they take a chicken which looks like it is pre-cooked as it is yellowish in colour, and put it on the grill

This is the case with restaurants like Nandos etc. During the grilling they apply the sauces and then serve

How do they precook the chicken? Do they marinate it and use an oven to heat it?

Comment: Nando's chicken is definitely marinaded, but I'm not sure about precooked. Perhaps an acid in the marinade gives it a cooked appearance.

Comment: I doubt any would boil it in water -- not only will it leach flavor, but they have more difficulty in controlling the shape (it might curl, making it obvious that it wasn't grilled the whole way).  If they pre-cooked it, they likely would've done it in a low oven ... but if they do it, they won't develop the same grill marks as they would from grilling raw chicken.  They would be better off slicing it into cutlets for faster & more even cooking times.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering explicitly about Nandos, it is marinated for 24 hours before its cooked. It is then cooked before its ordered:

> [The chickens] are cooked in a special oven for an average cycle of 30 minutes,
>   reaching a temperature of at least 75C, then kept in a warming drawer
>   at a temperature of 63C.

[Source](http://www.nandos.co.uk/faq/how-nandos-chicken-cooked)

When an order is placed, they take the Chicken and finish it on the grill.